# Questions about properly closing/committing database transactions and executing queries

Tags: java, coding-style

I'm working on updating a project and I just want to know best practices of these two questions:

1. Should I continue to use Connections/Statements/ResultSet for executing queries or should I be using something else?
2. Is this the correct way to commit/close Connections/Statements/ResultsSets? I mean am I doing the commits/closes in the correct order with the try/catch/finally blocks in the right places?

Please provide modified code examples of these snippets to make your point clear.

A snippet of code from a `select` type method:

```
public  ArrayList getMethod() {

    ArrayList a = new ArrayList();

    Connection con = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Statement stmt = null;

    try {

        con = BoneCPConnection.getConnectionPool().getConnection();     // get a connection
        con.setAutoCommit(true);            
        stmt = con.createStatement();

        String query = "select * from example";

        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        while(rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("Result: "+ rs.getInt(1));
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Issue with getMethod");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        try {
            rs.close();
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            con = null;
        }

        rs = null;
        stmt = null;
        con = null;
    }

    return a;
}
```

A snippet of code from an `update` type method

```
public void updateMethod() {

    ArrayList a = new ArrayList();

    Connection con = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    int updateCount = null;

    try {

        con = BoneCPConnection.getConnectionPool().getConnection();     // get a connection     
        stmt = con.createStatement();

        String query = "update example set id = 1";

        updateCount = stmt.executeUpdate(query);

        System.out.println("Result: "+ updateCount);    

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Issue with updateMethod");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

        try {
            con.commit();
            stmt.close();
            con.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            con = null;
        }

        stmt = null;
        con = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At a minimum, you should probably switch to `PreparedStatement` instead of plain Statements. The reason for this is that the JDBC driver will, in most cases, send the statement to the database upon creation so it can be precompiled. You can then bind your parameters to the statement and execute. Beyond the performance benefits of precompilation, you also get a *little* bit of protection against SQL injection attacks since way in which you set the parameters is more strongly typed. There is a good [description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) of prepared statements on Oracle's site.

If you're using Spring (or want to take the leap to add it to your system), you can take a look at the `JdbcTemplate`  and `JdbcDaoSupport` classes (both outlined [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/jdbc.html)). The main advantage is that it takes care of the connection cleanup code for you (so you don't have to worry as much about missing a `close` call).

Similarly, if you add Spring to your project, you can look at using it to configure your transactions (either via annotations or from with the Spring context file). This will allow you to pull the transaction management out of the actual implementation and make the code within your Dao a bit cleaner.

As for your handling of commit/close: you should move your commit statements out of your finally blocks and into the main execution path. You should keep your close statements in the finally block, though since you want to ensue they occur no matter what.

An example of what your update code would look like using PreparedStatements is:

```
public void updateMethod() {
    Connection con = null;
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    int updateCount = null;

    try {
        con = BoneCPConnection.getConnectionPool().getConnection();
        stmt = con.prepareStatement("update example set id = ?");        
        stmt.setInt(1,1);
        updateCount = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
        con.commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
       if(con != null){
        con.rollback();
       }
    } finally {

        try {
          if(stmt != null){
            stmt.close();
          }
          if(con != null){                
            con.close();
          }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            con = null;
        }        
    }
}
```

If you were using Spring's JdbcDaoSuport, it would look like:

```
public class YourDao extends JdbcDaoSupport{

  public void updateMethod(){
    String sql = "update example set id = ?";
    getJdbcTemplate().update(sql, new Object[] { new Integer(1)});           
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. You should almost always prefer PreparedStatement for parametrized queries as it:

   - protects you from sql injection
   - gets precompiled by database
2. You don't need to reinitialize rs, stmt and con to null as they go out of scope at the end of the method
3. You're almost always better off using some db access framework. One example is Spring with it's JdbcTemplate, another is Apache Commons DBUtils
4. If you're updating the system, update it to java 7 - you'll get try-with-resources that will close your connections and statements for free and your code will look like this:

```
    public void updateMethod() {
        int updateCount = 0;

        String query = "update example set id = ?";
        try (Connection con = BoneCPConnection.getConnectionPool().getConnection();                         
            PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
                stmt.setInt(1, 1);

                updateCount = stmt.executeUpdate();

                System.out.println("Result: " + updateCount);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Issue with updateMethod");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList getMethod() {

        ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
        String query = "select * from example";

        try (Connection con = BoneCPConnection.getConnectionPool().getConnection(); 
            Statement stmt = con.createStatement()) {

            con.setAutoCommit(false);

            try (
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query)) {

                while (rs.next()) {
                    System.out.println("Result: " + rs.getInt(1));
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Issue with getMethod");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return a;

    }
```

Comment: Good to know about java 7, but I don't have control to update that so that's not an option at this point.

Answer (score 3):

the most important thing to close is the connection.  generally, you want to try/finally each resource (rs, stmt, conn) when closing.

also, you don't want to commit in the finally block.  you only want to commit in the happy path (inside the catch block).

lastly, *never, ever, ever* put "e.printStackTrace()" in your code.

UPDATE:

Explanation for previous caveat about `printStackTrace()`: It is a code smell and it most likely means the program is swallowing the exception.  it gets automatically inserted by IDE's or manually inserted by programmers and pretty much means they aren't *actually* handling the exception.  some day, some where, they will want to see that exception, but it will be lost forever.  (then there's the worst case scenario where the code accidentally continues on like the exception never happened leaving the code in a borked state).  There are fundamentally 2 choices:

- if you want to continue after the exception, write it to a proper logging facility (use java.util.Logger if nothing else)
- if you can't handle the exception, re-throw it

(technically, there is also the *few and far between* case where it is a *truly* ignorable exception, in which case put a comment in like `// i never, ever care if i get this exception`).

Comment: `lastly, never, ever, ever put "e.printStackTrace()" in your code.` Why not?

Comment: @Dave - updating answer, too much to write in comment.

Comment: Ok, code smell, I'll buy that. However, it doesn't mean it's wrong, just a flag for unfinished business; I think the "never, ever, ever" is a little strong without a caveat of "in final delivered code." You made me think I was unaware of some side effect.

Comment: @Dave - the thing is, it _is_ wrong.  if you don't want to deal with handling that exception at that point in time, then just let it bubble up or re-throw it with an appropriate wrapper.  that's just as easy as putting in printStackTrace() and it doesn't have any of the risks of accidentally swallowing the exception.  there's no good reason to ever put that in your code.

Comment: @Dave - there is a side effect: the exception is stopped and it's unlikely that anyone will see that stack trace, aka "hiding a bug".

Answer (score 2):

Answer to question 1:
- if you are not a big fun of frameworks and your DB interaction business logic is simple enough, you can continue using this approach. Other alternatives are:
Hibernate, JPA or Spring JDBC. All of them are doing same thing, similar to your code but is hidden in framework implementation. Each of those frameworks come with their own advantages/dis-advantages. But again is a matter of preference/requirements/complexity.

Answer to question 2:
- you are doing open/close resources in the right order, however there are some issues:
1. Try to catch a more specific exception and not Exception. SQLException should be catched in  your example.
2. Is better to use PreparedStatement instead of Statement, in order to avoid SQL  injection or if you run same query multiple times.
3. Production code should not use System.out.println or e.printStackTrace, but for spikes or  exercising new stuff is not an issue. (In regards to previous answer).